# CustomLink provider is working on english but not on other languages

Tags: link-manager

I've built a custom link provider which returns the complete url when the linked item is not from context website. It works as expected on english, but even if I add `options.Language = Sitecore.Context.Language;` on the other languages, it doesnt work. The override method looks like below:

```
public override string GetItemUrl(Item item, ItemUrlBuilderOptions options)
    {
        options.Language = Sitecore.Context.Language;
        if (some_conditions)
        {
            options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
        }

        return base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
    }
```

The urls look the below:

On english: http://notTheContextSite/en/TestPage - ok

On german (for example): http://contextSite/de/sitecore/content/notTheContextSite/home/TestPage - not ok

Any ideas what can I do?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to debug? Is your code being called?

Comment: Is it working if you use http://notTheContextSite/de/TestPage? Also, how is the link provider patched in the configs?

Comment: @Gatogordo, yes, it works, when I inspect the return value of base.GetItemUrl(item, options); the url already looks as it shouldn't, on language versions.

Comment: @CristiVulturar, it works on all pages, on all websites, in english. On language versions, the url is "broken".